# Access to GtkLabel by the GtkBuilder

Tags: c++, gtkmm, glade

How can I access the label elements (GtkLabel) to change the text at runtime? With this code, I get a compile error.

**lottozahlen.cpp**

```
Gtk::Window* pWindow = 0;
Gtk::Label* pLabel = 0;

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  Gtk::Main kit (argc, argv);
  Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder> refBuilder = Gtk::Builder::create_from_file ("ui/main.glade");

  refBuilder->get_widget ("mainWindow", pWindow);
  refBuilder->get_widget ("label_1", pLabel);

  kit.run (*pWindow);

  return (0);
}
```

**Compiler Error**

```
/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm/builder.h:628:93: error: incomplete type ‘Gtk::Label’ used in nested name specifier
 widget = dynamic_cast<T_Widget*>(this->get_widget_checked(name, T_Widget::get_base_type()));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you just need to include the gtkmm/label.h header. Including gtkmm.h should give you everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

**Rule No1.** Never forget to test if pointers are valid before using them

I can't test my statement right now since I don't use glade but from what I remember you need to load a specific widget first, by specifying it's name as second parameter like so:

```
try // never assume the file exist, it may be removed
{
     Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder> refBuilder =
            Gtk::Builder::create_from_file ("ui/main.glade", "label_1"); // we want label!!
}
catch ( Glib::Error& ex )
{
       std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
}
```

Now once the label is loaded we get a pointer to the label like so:

```
Gtk::Label* pLabel = 0;
refBuilder->get_widget ("label_1", pLabel); // OK now we have label

if ( pLabel ) // this is the only way to test if pointer is valid
{
      // use pLabel
}
else // label load failed
{
      // handle error
      std::cerr << "label load failed\n" << std::endl;
}
```

You must also make sure the `"label_1"` is the correct name referenced in `*.glade` file

Comment: Everything you write is correct. But none of that is my problem. Sorry.

Comment: The point of my code above is that you should be able to debug the root of your problem by checking pointers and and using try catch to see what exactly fails. just running code without debugging won't help to much. You need to ensure the glade file has the "label_1" first and also check if file is loaded and so on... try so and see yourself.. if possible post your output.

Comment: The questioner has a compilation problem, not a runtime problem.